# add property to sibling if element contains specific value

Tags: jquery, forms

Just started with javascript/jquery

I have the follwing form ( generated, so no control on output)
and want to make it required if the label contains <em>*</em>

```
<div class="product-configure-options-option">
  <label for="product_configure_option_112843">Aantal verpakkingen links: <em>*</em></label>
  <select name="option[112843]" id="product_configure_option_112843">
    <option value="467619" selected="selected">Geen</option>
    <option value="467631">1</option>      
    <option value="467623">5</option>

  </select>
  <div class="product-configure-clear"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried the following code.
so if the div contains a label that contains the em, find the closest select and add the property required.

```
$( "product-configure-options-option label" ).has( "em" )(function() {
 $(this).find('select').prop('required',true);
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're looking for a class, add `.` before it.
2. JQuery selectors return an object, you can't invoke a an anonymous
   method by an object like this.
3. `.find()` is looking for elements inside other elements, use
   `.next()` instead.

```js
var labelsWithEm = $(".product-configure-options-option label").has("em"); // find all relevant items 

labelsWithEm.each(function() { // iterate the items
  $(this).next('select').prop('required', true); // find the next sibling that is select, and add the prop
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-configure-options-option">
  <label for="product_configure_option_112843">Aantal verpakkingen links: <em>*</em>
  </label>
  <select name="option[112843]" id="product_configure_option_112843">
    <option value="467619" selected="selected">Geen</option>
    <option value="467631">1</option>
    <option value="467623">5</option>

  </select>
  <div class="product-configure-clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:

1. `$( "product-configure-options-option ...` looks for an element with a *tag* called "product-configure-options-option."  You want an element with that *class* instead, which you can get by prepending a period:  `$( ".product-configure-options-option ...`
2. `$(this).find('select')` looks for a SELECT element that's a *child* of the label.  You want its sibling instead, which you can get with `$(this).next('select')`.